# Azure DevOps add PR automatic approval API call not working

Tags: pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

We are running DevOps server and in the past had a PS script that set automatic approvals for 2 reviewers using the System.AccessToken value, one of which is the build server account and the other is a group. We recently had to change the group to a new one and in the script, we had to update the group GUID to the new group and now I keep getting the following error

> Invoke-RestMethod :
> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid argument
> value.\r\nParameter name: TF401186: You cannot record a vote for
> someone else

Here is my section on trying do a PUT for the vote. This works for the user who creates the PR, but not the other group.

```
$voteURL = "https://dev.azure.com/blank/blank/_apis/git/repositories/blank/pullrequests/14848/reviewers/60a35ff8-f5bb-49f5-a298-36f2e915cf24?api-version=6.0"
Write-Host $voteURL
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $voteURL -Method Put -Headers $head -Body $jsonBody -ContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
Write-Host "response is: $response"
```

Ideas, as google has not been helpful and I am confused as to why this stopped working beyond MS changing something possibly?
ty

Googling and various iterations of the API call and anyone other than PR creator produces that error